# Regex to remove space after first parenthesis and before last parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove the space after the first parenthesis and the space before the last parenthesis of the following strings:

```
POINT ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228 )
POINT ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 )
POINT Z ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228 )
POINT Z ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 )
```

The results would be:

```
POINT (-68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228)
POINT (-68.1712366598 -16.5122344611)
POINT Z (-68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228)
POINT Z (-68.1712366598 -16.5122344611)
```

I can get the first space but having issues with the last space.

```
^\w*\s*\((\s*)
```

Please see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zuFjo7/3) for my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `.replace(/\(\s*(.*?)\s*\)/,"($1)"))`

The idea is to use a non greedy capture, `.*?`, to capture what's between the two parts to replace.

Demonstration:

```js
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input")
  .innerHTML.split("\n")
  .map(line=>line.replace(/\(\s*(.*?)\s*\)/,"($1)"))
  .join("\n");
```

```html
<pre id=input>
POINT ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228 )
POINT ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 )
POINT Z ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228 )
POINT Z ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 )
</pre>
<pre id=output>
</pre>
```

Comment: Simple, I like it. I updated your `\s` tokens to include a `*` quantifier so that cases like `POINT ( 5 4 10)` (or any other variant of spaces) would be covered. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex with captured regex for replacements:

```
String repl = str.replace(/^([^(]+\()\s*([^)]+?)\s*\)/, "$1$2)");
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuFjo7/6)

Comment: In your demo, switch the flavor to javascript

Answer (score 0):

Simple and understandable solution, even though not necessarily optimal:

```js
var input = 'POINT ( -68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228 )';

var formatted = input
  .replace(/\( +/g, '(')
  .replace(/ +\)/g, ')');

console.log(formatted); // "POINT (-68.1712366598 -16.5122344611 4124.6247727228)"
```